# Discard unprintable characters returned in server's XML response

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, bing-api

While trying to use the Bing API to search, I am getting characters that are not printable and do not seem to hold any extra information. The goal is to save the XML (UTF-8) response as a text file to be parsed later.

My code currently looks something like this:

```
    URL url = new URL(queryURL);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(query+"-"+saveResultAs));
    String str = in.readLine();
    out.write(str);

    in.close();
    out.close();
```

When I send the contents of 'str' to console it looks something like this:

[image]

and here's a what the newly created local XML file looks like:

[image]

What should I be doing to convert the UTF-8 text so that str does not have the extra characters?

Comment: that's a transcoding bug; use an XML parser or detect the encoding prior to decoding to a string: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-guessing I'm assuming you need a string - if you just want to save the file locally, read and write bytes.

Comment: @McDowell I ended up reading and writing bytes directly to the file. Using String was self-imposed limitation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know upfront the encoding you should

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

And the same with the writer... in your example after writing your file is encoded in platform default, while still declaring to be UTF-8.

It may be wise to read the encoding from the XML declaration to avoid surprises.

If you only want to store the data for later use there's no use to encode/decode anyway. Just read the bytes and write them away. Keep the task of detecting encoding for the XML parser..

Comment: providing InputStreamReader with the "UTF-8" helped me down the right track. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The XML parser will handle encoding/decoding, and the appropriate characters will be fed back to you (e.g. a SAX parser will do this via the `characters()` method callback). All you need to do is then store that in a suitable file (perhaps with a suitable [Byte-Order-Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?)

Comment: I will keep this suggestion in mind, but currently my task is only to save the file locally. Thanks!